# Sanitize RSS Feed content for a Feed Aggregator

Tags: php, javascript, rss, html-encode

I'm building a RSS feed aggregator/reader in PHP. Since RSS is essentially user generated content, I do not want to rely on the feed contents being safe.

I'm looking for advice on sanitizing the feed contents for storage and display on user's devices. Currently, I'm using `htmlentities(feed_content)` to escape all characters but that does not work right since it UTF-8 encodes the characters which cannot be decoded back in Javascript (That I use for frontend construction).

```
- Original: "Soundtrack: Dinosaur Jr. - Don’t Pretend You Didn’t Know I hadn’t thought much..."

- After htmlentities: "Copyright-Infringing Tweets Will Now Be &amp;#8220;Withdrawn&amp;#8221; Instead of &amp;#8220;Disappeared..."

- After JS decodeURI: "Copyright-Infringing Tweets Will Now Be &amp;#8220;Withdrawn&amp;#8221; Instead of &amp;#8220;Disappeared..."
```

If I remove the htmlentities above, the text shows correctly. But I'm not sure if that is the right way to ensure the data is sanitized

Answer (score 1):

pass the correct charset to htmlencode:

```
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

...but usually it's not necessary to do that. Just make sure you set the correct headers so the browser interprets correctly as utf8:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

or if you load using json:

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```